# Showing a layout to the Bridges puzzle has no solutions

Tags: graph-theory

I have a set of nodes $E$ and every node has an associated degree $i$ with it ($1 \leq i \leq 8$). The nodes are set up on a grid, and each node can only connect to a node it directly sees horizontally or vertically (no diagonal connections allowed). Moreover, between a pair of nodes that see each other, I can have either $0$, $1$, or $2$ connections.

The goal is to connect the nodes in such a way so that each node has as many edges as its required degree; none of the edges "cross" (when viewed on a grid); and the resulting graph is fully connected (I can reach every node from every other node).

This is the game [Bridges](http://www.puzzle-bridges.com/) in case my above explanation is confusing. Basically I have a multigraph with constraints on what node can connect to what node, and with $2$ maximum edges.

Question:

Given such a layout of nodes with their associated degrees, I'm trying to think of a way to show that there is or isn't a solution for said layout. For example, for a layout I came up with, I was able to find a non-solution (the nodes agreed on the degrees, but the resulting graph was not fully connected), but I couldn't come up with a correct solution. I guess I'm looking for some intuition on a decision procedure to show a given layout for the game of Bridges has no solutions (without solving it directly by enumerating all the possible connections, but by using some graph theoretical properties).

Comment: This is likely to be difficult; the question of whether there's a valid layout of bridges satisfying the constraint is (unsurprisingly) NP-complete.  Searching for 'Hashiwokakero NP-complete' should find you some good references on this.